# alternative to php to perform data mining computation

Tags: php, zend-framework, machine-learning

i'm working on a website that performs a lot of data mining and machine learning calculation thus very computationally expensive

i'm using zend framework, redis and mysql to build the website and so far everything works perfect because the traffic isnt that huge  
however i'm feeling that at some point , when the traffic is bigger ,i will have to worry about the performance of php  doing huge Data analysis and a lot of computation. 
i wanna tackle the problem now and think about an alternative solution to php to perform all my data mining and machine learning operations. 
 i was thinking about setting up a job server and rewrite some codes in C or C++ and call it from php with gearman or any library that does work distribution.
 what do you guys think ?

 i just wanna know if there are better options  out there ?

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would fit your scenario or if you've already tried it, but Zend Framework has [Zend_Queue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html) that can talk to messaging/queue servers or store them later for php to process.  See the [Zend Queue Adapters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.adapters.html) for references on powerful job processors you can talk to with zend.

You could also write the intense processing stuff in C/C++ and execute them directly from ZF you would just need to figure out a way to wait for the jobs to complete, or something to periodically check for completed jobs.